# 複数のrowを同時にIDを使いそれぞれ異なる値で更新する方法について

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql

このような`id`と`name`のHashの配列があった時に、一括で変更するためのSQLは以下のようなものになると本家のStackoverflowで回答されていたのですが、

```
[{id: 7, name: 'Bob'}, {id: 34, name: 'Mike'}]
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32159616/sql-update-multiple-rows-on-specific-ids

```
UPDATE table_name
SET    name = CASE id WHEN 7  THEN 'Bob'
                      WHEN 34 THEN 'Mike
              END
WHERE  id IN (7, 34)
```

このSQLをRailsで書くうまい方法はありますか？

なければ生SQLで行こうと思ってるのですが、
何かいい方法があるなら知りたく質問いたしました。

Comment: 配列の部分をゴニョゴニョして、User.update([7, 34], [{name: "bob"}, {name: "mike"}]) じゃダメですかね?

Comment: こんな書き方があったんですね。勉強になります。ただこの方法ですとSQL文は一件ずつ探してきてupdate処理をしてるようで、それなら普通に`each`で回したほうが良い気がします…。